# Compiling a Visual Studio dll and using it with cygwin

Tags: c, portaudio

my question is very simple.

I'm dealing with portaudio with the support of ASIO drivers for a university assignment. With Visual Studio I managed to compile everything an also to create a dll and now I must do the same but with cygwin. Is it possible to use the dll created with Visual Studio 2019 with cygwin? If it isn't, there is a way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't Cygwin require a shared library?  (Visual Studios would produce `.dlls`

Comment: My understanding is that you would have to compile within cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must have myfile.h myfile.dll and myfile.lib .

your goal is to produce myfile.a and put it in lib directory.

For that there is a tool Lib2a that take  myfile.dll and myfile.lib in input and give myfile.a file.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/lib2a/downloads